# Azure pay-as-you-go

Tags: windows, azure

As I read there is no way of setting a spending limit on an Azure VM. I have a small VM to play with. I use it for my homebrew blog platform and for experimenting with different things. Because I am a private I fear that I all sudden is going to pay 1000 $ a month because of a random dDOS or something alike. How am I going to assure that this is not going to happen? I have set up a warning mail, but this is only a mail. I do not like this. Does there exist some sort of asp.net handler or software to protect against to many requests at once?

Comment: Probably better to post this on ServerFault since it's not programming-related. That said: What costs are you concerned with? VM costs are billed by the minute, not by usage. Storage transactions are a penny per 100,000. Inbound bandwidth is free. Outbound bandwidth is free for first 5GB, then 12 cents per GB per month.

Comment: Concerned about transaction and outbound bandwith. But as you say, it is really cheap. I am going to post it on serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working privately then the simple solution here is to restrict access to your service by IP - that way only you have access and you wouldn't need to worry about things like DoS.

Comment: I am a private. But I am hosting my blog on the VM. I am doing this to get some experience with the platform. But I am fearing that I am going to spend way to much.

Comment: In what respect? Azure is fairly cheap and also has thresholds for something's before they start to charge

Comment: I know of the thresholds, and it is cheap, but still, is there a way to be proactive?

Comment: @mslot you mean like turn off the VM when it breaches a threshold? Don't think that sort of behavior comes out the box but that's not to say you couldn't develop a system to do that. In fairness, Azure do a fairly good job on letting you know when all this stuff is happening and provide you with free options (or really cheap options) for development. You can run an ExtraSmall VM for less than £10 p/m. Also, considering it's just a blog (and you don't depend on some 3rd party install) then why not just develop using a free website and deploy to a web role?

Comment: Yes turn it of, or restrict the access from certain IPs or so, fpr a minute or a hour. I want to have the ability to use TC to deploy to four different environments (staging, test and such). Just to get hands on with TC also. And with that run unit tests and so on. That is why I am using a VM and not websites. So I think I am going to do some sort of restricted access, just to calm my mind a bit.

Comment: I have accepted this as of letting me know that Azure is cheap and I can do some sort of IP restriction.

Comment: @mslot you don't need me to tell you that Azure is cheap, they have a [calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/). I've got to be honest I am still pretty confused as to what it is you are trying to do here - you *claim* this is for development but it *sounds* like you are actually looking to do is get a blog hosted on Azure for free - you can do this but it would need to be using the Free Website option (which is not recommended for production). Alternatively, look at the Shared website option, 1 website would cost you around £6 p/m.

Comment: I am _not_ trying to anything for free. And I _am_ using this as a development server, as well as for hosting my blog. I _know_ that it is cheap, but as I am being a private, I am _not_ made of money. That is why I am concerned.

Comment: @mslot I am all for getting stuff for free, however, a lot of the time you get what you pay for. *"I am using this as a development server, as well as for hosting my blog"* - so when you say development server - do you mean *for* your blog or for other stuff?

Comment: Both for my blog and for other things. I have three setups so I can test my blog, and one for production. This is a hobby of mine. I do also use it for a homebrewed IRC bot that is using MSMQ etc. So I cannot get a website. I have to have a VM.